Can't connect to DB with QGIS DB Manager
I'm have just started to explore Postgis ext and I'm trying to load demo data from https://postgis.gishub.org/chapters/postgis_intro.html to my DB with QGIS (ersion 3.36.1). I can successfuly connect to DB with Postgis ext and I see it in QGIS Browser, but when I try to connect in QGIS DB Manager, I have an error :

SQL error: SELECT has_table_privilege('"geometry_columns"', 'SELECT'),
has_table_privilege('"geometry_columns"', 'INSERT'),
has_table_privilege('"geometry_columns"', 'UPDATE'),
has_table_privilege('"geometry_columns"', 'DELETE') returned 0 [ERROR:
relation "geometry_columns" does not exist ]

The tables exist of course and the same query works well when I delete the "" quotes in tables names
How can I fix it in DBManager and connect?

The thing is, I'v installed postgis extansion not in "public" scheme, ok, but I can't find the setting to change "public" to "another"
